# How to play flv file in WPF Media element

Tags: wpf

I want to play flv file in WPF MediaElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install a flv DirectShow filter.  Try playing in Windows Media Player.  If it works, try using it in MediaElement.  If that does not work, it should work with the MediaUriElement in my [WPF MediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/)